# Raspberry Pi zero W - Sharing files wirelessly to a Windows device without internet connection

Tags: wireless, pi-zero, file-sharing

I'm actually working on this project where we have to transfer images taken by the raspberry pi zero W wirelessly to another device. I know that this model of raspberry pi has a wireless network (wifi/Bluetooth) built in and I just want to be able to connect to the raspberry pi and transfer the files wirelessly. I'm on Windows and using putty. (no raspian OS on my pc).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and maybe opinion based. There are many possibilities to transfer data wireless between devices. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this, but without detail some of them may not be what you want.  You could use "scp" (secure copy) on the Pi and install WinSCP on Windows.  You can enable Samba/CIFS on the Pi -- which allows you to create a network filesystem (Windows would attach to the Pi as a network fileserver).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Copy files Off a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43808/how-to-copy-files-off-a-raspberry-pi)